# R: change x-axis direction

Tags: r, plot

`plot(runif(12))` creates a plot with x-axis numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. In this way, the positive direction is left-to-right.

It is possible to define the possitive direction from right to left?.

Something like `plot(runif(12), xAxisDirection='right-to-left')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the range and pass it to `xlim` parameter in plot

```
x <- runif(12)
plot(x, xlim=rev(range(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the labels and plot the x axis separately:

```
set.seed(123)
v   = runif(12)
lab = seq(1, length(v), by = 2)
lab = lab[order(-lab)]
lab.at = length(v) - lab + 1

plot(v, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = lab.at, labels = lab)
```

[image: plot]
For other data (e.g. meaningful x labels) you could create an artificial x value that is plotted (e.g. `x.plot = min(x) - x`) to sort the data while you label the x axis with values of your x variable.